# I can't access "TextView" or "Button" in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new at Kotlin, Android Studio. I have worked loops, statements. Then I wanted to pass to the layouts. However, I can't access the things that I put activity_main.xml in MainActivity.kt .
For example, I put a TextView in my project. And I want to change its text by writing
' IdOfTextView.text = "Hi" '
However, when I wrote the ID of my textView, the color of its turning red. And said "Unresolved reference : myTextId". It is happening to other things like "button" too. How can I solve it?

[firstPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPpHp.png)
[secondPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsCEL.png)

I've tried :
clear&reboot
Delete the program and install again

Solution :
All I needed is add " id 'kotlin-android-extensions' "in my build.grade file. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `findViewById`, you have to get access to this `TextView`, then you can call methods and set some values on it

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = "Hi"
```

this is "basic", most common way for accessing inflated (set by `setContentView`) `View`s. its pretty old, comes from very beggining of Android OS developement, oftenly used in Java

now we have an extension for Kotlin which allows you to ommit `findViewById`, it is done for you under the hood. `View` variables are named just like their ids. for this feature use below lines (put them in `build.gradle` file):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' // most important
```

then you have to import some file auto-generated by extension plugin - kind-of map of `View`s generated basing on XML set with `setContentView` (thanks to MMD, who pointed this in comment). put this line on top of your `MainActivity`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

more details in [HERE](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

Comment: also you need to import your layout to your activity like this `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Kotlin Android Extensions` which is a Kotlin plugin that will allow recovering view from Activities, Fragments and Views

To use it, you need to apply the plugin in your `build.gradle`

Add this below your compiler plugins

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And that’s all you need. You’re now ready to call your view as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I added it and it is working now.